# hive insert current date into a table using date function errors

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-streaming

I have to insert current date (timestamp) in a table via hive query. The query is failing for some reason. Can someone please help me out.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataFlagTest(
            date string          
    ) 
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 's3://bckt1/hive_test/dateFlag/';
```

Now To insert into it, I run following query :

```
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dataFlagTest  
    SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) ;
```

It failed with the following error :

```
 FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Solution is you have to do select from a table. You cannot run select without from clause.

So, create a sample table with 1 row or use an existing table like below :

```
 Insert OVERWRITE TABLE dataflagtest SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as date FROM EXISTING_TABLE TABLESAMPLE(1 ROWS);
```